# Bash script - how to count processes that have most parents

Tags: bash

we were given a task to write a script in a course. We have to make the script find out which proccess is "deepest" in process hierarchy, something like "pstree" command, but the output will be "depth_of_process : processes_with_the_depth".

I have started something, but I can't make it work. Could you please look at it and help me ? I haven't even started producing the output, I am working on the algorithm now - trying to make it into something like reverse depth-first search. In case the code is not self-explanatory enough, please let me know, I will do my best to describe it.

```
#!/bin/bash

PROCS=$(ps -eo "%p %P" | tail -n +2 | sort -nr)


declare -a array
while read -r line; do
    counter=1
    read kid parent
    while read -r otherline; do
        read kid2 parent2
        if [ "$parent" = "$kid2" ]; then
            counter=$((counter+1))
            parent="$parent2"
        fi
    done <<< "$PROCS"
    test=2
    array["$kid"]="$counter"
done <<< "$PROCS"

#for value in "${!array[@]}"; do
#   echo "$value ${array[value]}"
#done
echo "$PROCS"
```

Comment: How in bash does it need to be, like can you use awk/perl/sed whatever ?

Comment: @123 bash commands and utilites, so all of those you wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If pstree is allowed I could offer this (thanks @tripleee for optimizing):

```
for processid in $(ps -ax | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}' ); do
    depth=$(pstree -sA $processid | head -n1 | sed -e 's#-+-.*#---foobar#' -e 's#---*#\n#g' -eq | wc -l)
    echo "$depth: $processid"
done
```

It might have issues if your processes contain two or more dashes in a row.

Of course you can add " | sort" after "done" to get the deepest processes.

Comment: `awk | sed` is kind of useless.  Try `$(ps -ax | awk 'NR>1 { print $1 }')`. Similarly, the `head | sed | sed` should be refactored to a single `sed` script: `sed -e 's#-+-.*#---foobar#' -e 's#---*#\n#g' -eq`.

Comment: great solution ! just btw, wouldn't writing out only PID's with ps be even more effective ?

Comment: well upon testing it - I found out it doesn't actually work flawlessly. It said that two processes have the same "depth" but one of them was parent process of the other one